# Change wordpress post urls in publish page with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

Wordpress is changing "**Post Titles**" to "**post-titles**" when we first enter the title (*Done with ajax ?*).
For a specific custom post type, i need to remove "-" in urls of the posts. So they will be "posttitles"

I’ve been doing it manually for a while but i believe i can force urls to remove "-" among them. This post type usually have 2 words titles and at most 3 words titles.

I understand its done through AJAX but i couldn’t separate the url rewrite code from the main batch (let alone devise a plugin that will alter it to my needs).
Any idea or suggestion is welcome at this point.

Also this is rather a backend problem and not a frontend problem. Otherwise i would have tried it with htacess. So our main target is wordpress publish page on admin panel.

Thank you

Edit:

Ive still not figurred out how to do this to specific custom post type.

I took Aggelos Synadakis code below and changed it to this.

The closest i came is this code.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'portfolioPermalinks');
function portfolioPermalinks($post, $title) {
$post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type == 'customposttype'){
        $var1 = sanitize_title($title);
    $title = str_replace(' ', '', $var1);
    return $title;
    }

}
```

This code makes rest of the sites posts to have normal urls while "customposttype" **url to be blank**. So in a way, i did manage to effect a specific post type but not the way i wanted.

Comment: What are you trying to replace the - with? Do you just want "Post Titles" slugs to become "posttitles"?

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot, ill add it now to main post. As for your question, yes thats what im exactly looking for. "posttitles"

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the default slug structure, try the following code to your functions.php file:

```
function my_custome_slug($title) {
    return str_replace(' ', '', $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'my_custome_slug');
```

In the same way, you can apply any other change you would like to the default slug format.

Comment: I cannot even begin to thank you enough. I was reading some Ajax tutorials to fix this problem and it was as simple as that.

I dont want to strech further but can you also explain how can i force this to a spesific post type?

Comment: I am glad my solution worked and solved your problem.

Comment: Hey Aggelos, i've tried to few things to limit this code for a specific custom post type but either it breaks (like ,nothing appears on the generated url part) or nothing happens (as in, still it becomes "post-title"). Can we limit this code to a specific custom post type?